# Running a cocoa app which requires keychain access from root terminal

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, macos-carbon, keychain

I am trying to run a cocoa app [KeychainTesterApp](http://agerson.net/example-some-common-uses-keychain) while I am logged in as root (sudo su).

Here are the steps:

Open terminal -> type sudo su -> Enter password.

Now, I want to open the app , so I do this: sudo -u username open KeychainTesterApp.app. The app starts up, except when I try to do anything related to the keychain I get the error Keychain not found - "A keychain cannot be found to store."

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having above might be that running:

```
sudo -u username open KeychainTesterApp.app
```

Will not open the app as root. To open a Cocoa app as root, run the actual executable as sudo:

```
sudo "SimpleKeychainExample.app/Contents/MacOS/SimpleKeychainExample"
```

I'm not sure why the app cannot find the keychain you're looking for.  Posting a code example from where that app is opening the Keychain might help clarify the question.

Comment: I do not want to run the app as root. I want to be able to access the user's keychain. It's more of a deployment issue for me (Since the deployment environment deploys everything while logged in as root).

Comment: You should post some code in your question. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do (step by step) which makes it hard to diagnose.